# Remove braces & symbols from output of apriori algorithm & join with another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R & stuck here. Searched forums & documents but no answers I found.

I have a scenario where rules output of apriori algorithm must be joined with another dataframe on the lhs & rhs values. I am able to create dataframe of the rules output but I am am unable to remove braces & => symbols & divide if any multiple itemsets are in lhs. Once this is done I have to join with a dataframe on lhs & rhs values to retrieve some more columns from other dataframe.

Below dataframe I created from rules output of apriori.

```
> RulesDf
                                             rules support confidence     lift
1               {0400000000002} => {0400000000001}     0.2          1 2.500000
2               {0400000000005} => {0400000000004}     0.2          1 1.666667
3               {0400000000007} => {0400000000008}     0.2          1 3.333333
4               {0400000000003} => {0400000000004}     0.3          1 1.666667
5 {0400000000001,0400000000003} => {0400000000004}     0.2          1 1.666667
```

Other dataframe which needs to be joined on lhs & rhs.

```
> store1inv
   store           UPC Inventory
1      1 0400000000001       100
2      1 0400000000002        10
3      1 0400000000003      1002
4      1 0400000000004        50
5      1 0400000000005        15
6      1 0400000000006        25
7      1 0400000000007       150
8      1 0400000000008       350
9      1 0400000000009       100
10     1 0400000000010        75
```

basically, I want to find out the inventory for all items in the rulesDf that starts with 04. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's being kept in the `RulesDf`'s first column?  For instance should `0400000000001`, `0400000000003`, and `0400000000004` all be kept?  If so how will they join with the second dataframe as there are multiple matches in the same cell.  You say "divide" if multiple items.  What does that mean?  I think your best bet is to show what "divide" means and then show what you expect the joined output to look like.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possibility, here's a copy/pastable format for your RulesDf

```
RulesDf <- structure(list(rules = c("{0400000000002} => {0400000000001}", 
"{0400000000005} => {0400000000004}", "{0400000000007} => {0400000000008}", 
"{0400000000003} => {0400000000004}", 
"{0400000000001,0400000000003} => {0400000000004}"
), support = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2), confidence = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), lift = c(2.5, 1.666667, 3.333333, 1.666667, 1.666667)), 
.Names = c("rules", "support", "confidence", "lift"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I'll use a regular expression to grab out the data from the brackets. I'm going to use a catpuring group and to make things easier i'm going to use a helper function called [regcapturedmatches()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10413321) to extract them.

```
rules <- regcapturedmatches(RulesDf$rules, 
    gregexpr("{([^}]*)}", RulesDf$rules, perl=T))
mrules <- lapply(rules, function(x) 
    cbind(left=strsplit(x[1],",")[[1]], right=x[2]))
```

If you'd rather use only base functions, then

```
rules<-regmatches(RulesDf$rules, gregexpr("{([^}]*)}", 
    RulesDf$rules, perl=T))
rules<-lapply(rules, function(x) gsub("[{}]","",x))
mrules <- lapply(rules, function(x) 
    cbind(left=strsplit(x[1],",")[[1]], right=x[2]))
```

should work as well in thie case.

Now i've also split those with comma to make them extra rows. Now i'll go ahead and re-combine with the original data

```
ExpRules <- cbind(RulesDf[rep(1:nrow(RulesDf), sapply(mrules, nrow)),], 
    do.call(rbind, mrules))
```

This will give us (leaving off the original "rules" column

```
    support confidence     lift          left         right
1       0.2          1 2.500000 0400000000002 0400000000001
2       0.2          1 1.666667 0400000000005 0400000000004
3       0.2          1 3.333333 0400000000007 0400000000008
4       0.3          1 1.666667 0400000000003 0400000000004
5       0.2          1 1.666667 0400000000001 0400000000004
5.1     0.2          1 1.666667 0400000000003 0400000000004
```

Then you can use the left and right columns to join to other tables.